# How to make c# analyzer from CLI, to warn on usage of ! operator

Tags: c#, roslyn, analyzer

Ok, as usual the msft docs are utterly useless for me.  Here is my Q:

How can I make an analyzer using the CLI (dotnet 6.0 SDK on linux) and have it run when I `dotnet build` other projects, and have it print warnings if the null forgiveness operator (!) is used.  I do NOT use visual studio.  Also how can I verify analyzers are even being loaded / initialized by dotnet build.

For context, we require a `__unwrap<T>()` helper method, which checks at runtime that the object is indeed not null, instead of sacrificing safety.  And this project here does not seem to work for me: https://github.com/tom-englert/Nullable.Extended#roslyn-analyzer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your aforementioned analyzer from nuget (for other people reading this: `dotnet add package Nullable.Extended.Analyzer`), you need to specify the severity of its diagnostic Ids (`NX0001..3`).

[There are multiple ways to do it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/configuration-files). Feel free to follow the *Global AnalyzerConfig* method if you prefer, but I'm going to use the `.editorconfig` file for the sake of simplicity (you might already have one):

```
[*.cs]
dotnet_diagnostic.NX0001.severity=warning
dotnet_diagnostic.NX0002.severity=warning
dotnet_diagnostic.NX0003.severity=warning
```

The 3 different Ids and some description can be found [in the source code](https://github.com/tom-englert/Nullable.Extended/blob/b770c730af330e0b2fd46b4cf1181c4898762d40/src/Nullable.Extended.Analyzer/Nullable.Extended.Analyzer/NullForgivingDetectionAnalyzer.cs).   You can also see there that the `DiagnosticDescriptor`'s are created with `DiagnosticSeverity.Info` - which are not shown when doing a `dotnet build` - hence the need to manually override as warnings.

Comment: I can confirm that your .editorconfig in the project directory works.  Thank you so much.